# Nested Case statement in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

My Query

```
Declare     @From       DateTime='01 Feb 2013'
Declare     @To         DateTime='28 Feb 2013 23:59:59'

Select 
            Case
                  When
                  (
                        Select TOP 1 f1.UpdatedOn
                        From TicketTypeFollowUp As f1 with(nolock)
                        Where f1.UpdatedOn<T.UpdatedOn And f1.Ticket=T.Ticket
                        Order By f1.UpdatedOn Desc
                  )IS Null
                  Then Ticket.TicketRaisedOn

                  Else
                  (
                       Select TOP 1 f1.UpdatedOn
                       From TicketTypeFollowUp As f1 with(nolock)
                       Where f1.UpdatedOn<T.UpdatedOn And f1.Ticket=T.Ticket
                       Order By f1.UpdatedOn Desc
                  ) End [Start Date]

      From dbo.TicketTypeFollowUp T with(nolock)
      --Some Tables Omitted          
      Where CAST(TicketRaisedOn As Date)Between ''+Convert(VarChar(19), @From, 100)+''       And ''+Convert(VarChar(19), @To, 100)+''
```

**If the Column `[Start Date]` has values Greater than `@To` Then `@To` Value should print Else [Start Date] Column**

How can i write it in the same query ?

What i tried

```
       Case When(
             Case
                  When
                  (
                        Select TOP 1 f1.UpdatedOn
                        From TicketTypeFollowUp As f1 with(nolock)
                        Where f1.UpdatedOn<T.UpdatedOn And f1.Ticket=T.Ticket
                        Order By f1.UpdatedOn Desc
                  )IS Null
                  Then Ticket.TicketRaisedOn

                  Else
                  (
                       Select TOP 1 f1.UpdatedOn
                       From TicketTypeFollowUp As f1 with(nolock)
                       Where f1.UpdatedOn<T.UpdatedOn And f1.Ticket=T.Ticket
                       Order By f1.UpdatedOn Desc
                  ) End [Start Date]
              )> @To Then @To Else [Start Date] End,
```

DB : SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: what error you are getting while modifing your query in your way as posted above?

Comment: At the first glance you nested `CASE-END` query looks reasonable.  What's wrong with it? Do you get any errors? Is your result different from what you expected to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you need this:

```
Declare     @From       DateTime='01 Feb 2013'
Declare     @To         DateTime='28 Feb 2013 23:59:59'

Select CASE WHEN ISNULL(StartDates.[Start Date], Ticket.TicketRaisedOn) > @To THEN @To ELSE ISNULL(StartDates.[Start Date], Ticket.TicketRaisedOn) END AS ResultValue
From dbo.TicketTypeFollowUp T with(nolock)
    --Some Tables Omitted 
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        Select TOP 1 f1.UpdatedOn AS [Start Date]
        From TicketTypeFollowUp As f1 with(nolock)
        Where f1.UpdatedOn<T.UpdatedOn And f1.Ticket=T.Ticket
        Order By f1.UpdatedOn Desc
    ) StartDates
Where CAST(TicketRaisedOn As Date)Between ''+Convert(VarChar(19), @From, 100)+''       And ''+Convert(VarChar(19), @To, 100)+''
```

The OUTER APPLY lets you specify a computed value per row, referencing values from the joined tables above, but after that it's rather like data coming from a JOIN. So you give your APPLY an alias as if it were a table and then access its value as many times as needed above.

As you can see, this dramatically simplifies your query-- APPLY is extremely handy to have in your tool belt.)))

**EDIT** Added another ISNULL per comment.

Comment: In Outer Apply...Case When Else End Condition Come ? as i have same in My Select query...

Comment: That should be taken care of by ISNULL in the CASE in the outer query, which will use the first value if it isn't NULL, otherwise the second value. On reflection, you may need it in the ELSE block there, too, though. I will edit my answer.